# beginner explanation average of specific field mongodb what is the difference between doing mapreduce or group

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

In the reference post, I sort of found my answer, but I am a beginner to MongoDB, and their documentation isn't exactly well explained for a beginner to it. I also am reading the book by Kristina, so I am doing my homework. I thought that this post might help other uses who are trying to figure this out as well, rather than the traditional, I have a problem, someone posts a code sample, and they never really understand what happened.

That being said, I am having a really tough time with a few interrelated things which I have listed below, I found another good question and answer about this problem, but it was just some code and not well explained for a beginner to mongo. Also the code didn't work for me (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6414312/fastest-way-to-get-the-average-of-a-specific-field-in-mongodb). :/

I have some documents like so:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4fc7e9138c8b0f0d5200000f"), "memtotal" : 996, "swaptotal" : 2015, "swapfree" : 2015, "memfree" : 464, "time" : 1338501393 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4fc7e9518c8b0f0d52000015"), "memtotal" : 996, "swaptotal" : 2015, "swapfree" : 2015, "memfree" : 464, "time" : 1338501455 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4fc7e98f8c8b0f0d5200001b"), "memtotal" : 996, "swaptotal" : 2015, "swapfree" : 2015, "memfree" : 463, "time" : 1338501517 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4fc7e9cd8c8b0f0d52000021"), "memtotal" : 996, "swaptotal" : 2015, "swapfree" : 2015, "memfree" : 464, "time" : 1338501579 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4fc7ea0b8c8b0f0d52000027"), "memtotal" : 996, "swaptotal" : 2015, "swapfree" : 2015, "memfree" : 446, "time" : 1338501641 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4fc7ea498c8b0f0d5200002d"), "memtotal" : 996, "swaptotal" : 2015, "swapfree" : 2015, "memfree" : 424, "time" : 1338501703 }
```

I am trying to get all of the memfree elements and then calculate the average. I tried copy/paste programming the code based on the above referenced link, first off it made sense up to a point, and second, it didn't actually work.

line 2) the first line makes sense, pretty self explanatory
line 3) the second line count: 0, total: 0 - are these true/false switches?
line 4) is this calling the same reduce from the mapReduce() function? Are doc and out keywords, or are we defining them arbitrarily?
other) the code failed anyway, why?

Last subquestion : Can I do the same thing using mapReduce and why would I use a mapReduce function versus a group on this, if I have shards I need to calculate the average from as well?

Answer (score 3):

This is mostly covered in the [documentation of the group function](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Aggregation#Aggregation-Group).

Let's break it down:

`db.test.group(`
 - Run this query on test collection and group results.
`{   cond: {"status": 1}`
 - I only care about documents which satisfy this condition, so filter my results.
`, initial: {count: 0, total:0}`
 - I'm going to track two variables, count and total, let's initialize them to zero in the output document.
`, reduce: function(doc, out){ out.count++; out.total += doc.views }`
 - For every document that satisfied the condition, apply this function (which will increment the count by one and increment the total by number of views in our document 'out'
`, finalize: function(out){ out.avg = out.total / out.count }`
 - When we've gone through all the documents, run this function which will compute average views by dividing total views by number of documents and put that in my 'out' document.
`} );`

There is also another line that didn't need to be in the referenced example `key` which would be needed if you wanted to group by specific fields.  Without it, you get the average for the entire collection.  With it, you get separate average for each distinct value of 'key'.

And yes, the reduce is the same function that you might write in map/reduce.  The limitation of "group" is that you only get "the document" that matches your condition.  In map reduce you can use the "map" function to emit an arbitrary document based on the input document.

The reason I asked about which version you were using is the [Aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/aggregation/) which is available now in the development release (2.1) and will be released in 2.2 for production greatly simplifies doing aggregated queries on MongoDB collections.

Hopefully this helped a little.